# Virgo problem: ClassNotFoundException for an exported class in a started bundle

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, eclipse-virgo

For some reason one of my bundles fails to load class from another:

```
[2011-09-08 10:57:55.574] Thread-2                     <UR0001I> User region ready. 
[2011-09-08 10:57:56.580] fs-watcher                   <HD0001I> Hot deployer processing 'INITIAL' event for file 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin-2.1.1.RELEASE.plan'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:02.127]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'poim_resources' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:14.291]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'poim_resources' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:14.360]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'poim_resources' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:14.402] fs-watcher                   <DE0000I> Installing plan 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.plan' version '2.1.1'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:14.436] Thread-3                     <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'poim_resources' version '0.0.0' with context path '/poim_resources'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:14.646] fs-watcher                   <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.core' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:14.882] Thread-3                     <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'poim_resources' version '0.0.0' with context path '/poim_resources'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:14.887] start-signalling-1           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'poim_resources' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:22.597] fs-watcher                   <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.512] fs-watcher                   <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.core' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.515] fs-watcher                   <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.519] fs-watcher                   <DE0001I> Installed plan 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.plan' version '2.1.1'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.530] fs-watcher                   <DE0004I> Starting plan 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.plan' version '2.1.1'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.539] fs-watcher                   <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.core' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.553] fs-watcher                   <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.564] fs-watcher                   <HD0001I> Hot deployer processing 'INITIAL' event for file 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE.par'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.599]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0000I> Installing plan 'pshd.plan' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.611]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0000I> Installing configuration 'ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.ssd.app' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.622] Thread-3                     <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE' with context path '/admin'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.776] start-signalling-2           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.core' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.924]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.poim-protocol' version '2.0.1'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:24.935]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.ssd.db' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:25.332] Thread-3                     <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE' with context path '/admin'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:25.336] start-signalling-1           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:25.342] start-signalling-1           <DE0005I> Started plan 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin.plan' version '2.1.1'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:25.544]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.ssd' version '3.1.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:25.604]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.jpa' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:25.620]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.video' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:25.625]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0000I> Installing configuration 'ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:25.851]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.572]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0001I> Installed configuration 'ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.ssd.app' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.576]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.poim-protocol' version '2.0.1'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.579]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.ssd.db' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.582]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.ssd' version '3.1.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.586]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.jpa' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.589]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.video' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.592]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0001I> Installed configuration 'ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.596]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.599]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-synthetic.context' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.602]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0001I> Installed plan 'pshd.plan' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.630]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0004I> Starting plan 'pshd.plan' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.646]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0004I> Starting configuration 'ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.ssd.app' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.658]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0005I> Started configuration 'ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.ssd.app' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.666]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.poim-protocol' version '2.0.1'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.678]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.ssd.db' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.678] start-signalling-1           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.poim-protocol' version '2.0.1'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.691]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.ssd' version '3.1.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.719]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.jpa' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.748]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.video' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.756]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0004I> Starting configuration 'ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.766] Thread-3                     <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.video' version '3.2.0' with context path '/video'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.798]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0005I> Started configuration 'ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server' version '0.0.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.858]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.891]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-synthetic.context' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:27.921] start-signalling-2           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-synthetic.context' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.047] fs-watcher                   <DE0000I> Installing par 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.053] fs-watcher                   <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository.core' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.061] fs-watcher                   <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.366] fs-watcher                   <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository.core' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.372] fs-watcher                   <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.378] fs-watcher                   <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-synthetic.context' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.384] fs-watcher                   <DE0001I> Installed par 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.451] fs-watcher                   <DE0004I> Starting par 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.459] fs-watcher                   <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository.core' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.471] fs-watcher                   <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.906] fs-watcher                   <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-synthetic.context' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.916] fs-watcher                   <HD0001I> Hot deployer processing 'INITIAL' event for file 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.splash-2.1.1.RELEASE.war'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:28.971] start-signalling-3           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-synthetic.context' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:29.030] Thread-3                     <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE' with context path '/org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:29.282] fs-watcher                   <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.splash' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:29.599] fs-watcher                   <DE0001I> Installed bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.splash' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:29.625] fs-watcher                   <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.splash' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:29.634] Thread-3                     <WE0000I> Starting web bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.splash' version '2.1.1.RELEASE' with context path '/'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:29.686] start-signalling-4           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository.core' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:30.093] start-signalling-4           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.ssd.db' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:32.121] Thread-3                     <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.video' version '3.2.0' with context path '/video'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:32.126] start-signalling-1           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.video' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:32.156] start-signalling-1           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.ssd' version '3.1.0'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:32.819] Thread-3                     <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.splash' version '2.1.1.RELEASE' with context path '/'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:32.838] start-signalling-3           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.splash' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:33.536] Thread-3                     <WE0001I> Started web bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE' with context path '/org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:33.540] start-signalling-2           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository-2.1.1.RELEASE-org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository.web' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:33.546] start-signalling-2           <DE0005I> Started par 'org.eclipse.virgo.apps.repository' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'. 
[2011-09-08 10:58:33.837] start-signalling-2           <DE0005I> Started bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.jpa' version '3.2.0'. 
[2011-09-07 16:46:13.569] start-signalling-1           <DE0006E> Start failed for bundle 'pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server' version '3.2.0'. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ru/focusmedia/odp/poim/protocol/AccessRights
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:787)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.agent.dm.ContextPropagatingTaskExecutor$2.run(ContextPropagatingTaskExecutor.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.ExtendedClassNotFoundException: ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.protocol.AccessRights in KernelBundleClassLoader: [bundle=pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server_3.2.0]
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.equinox.KernelBundleClassLoader.loadClass(KernelBundleClassLoader.java:139)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.protocol.AccessRights
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.equinox.KernelBundleClassLoader.loadClass(KernelBundleClassLoader.java:135)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

`ru.focusmedia.poim-protocol`, which is started successfully, is the bundle which contains the class, and it exports `ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.protocol` package:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: POIM_Protocol
Bundle-SymbolicName: ru.focusmedia.poim-protocol;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 2.0.1
Bundle-ClassPath: POIM_Protocol.jar
Export-Package: ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.protocol,
 ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.protocol.requests,
 ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.protocol.responses
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Require-Bundle: org.apache.mina.core;bundle-version="2.0.2",
 ru.focusmedia.comms-osgi;bundle-version="1.0.0"
Bundle-Vendor: Focus Media
Import-Package: org.slf4j;version="1.6.1",
 ru.focusmedia.jump,
 ru.focusmedia.jump.annotation,
 ru.focusmedia.jump.binding,
 ru.focusmedia.jump.binding.impl,
 ru.focusmedia.jump.binding.impl.headers,
 ru.focusmedia.jump.binding.impl.presencer,
 ru.focusmedia.jump.binding.impl.types,
 ru.focusmedia.jump.binding.spi,
 ru.focusmedia.jump.protocol,
 ru.focusmedia.jump.protocol.impl,
 ru.focusmedia.jump.protocol.spi
```

and `ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server` imports it:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: ru.focusmedia.pshd.server;uses:="ru.focusmedia.odp.psh
 d.domain.model,ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.integration",ru.focusmedia.pshd
 .server.poim;uses:="javax.xml.parsers,javax.xml.xpath,org.xml.sax,ru.
 focusmedia.pshd.server,ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.db,ru.focusmedi
 a.pshd.server.poim.db.entity,ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.protocol.
 impl.commands",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.cmdexec;uses:="ru.focus
 media.pshd.server,ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.protocol.impl.schema
 ",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.db;uses:="javax.measure,javax.measur
 e.unit,org.core,ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.domain.model,ru.focusmedia.odp
 .pshd.integration,ru.focusmedia.pshd.server,ru.focusmedia.pshd.server
 .poim,ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.db.entity,ru.focusmedia.pshd.ser
 ver.poim.protocol.impl.commands,ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.protoc
 ol.impl.schema",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.db.entity,ru.focusmedi
 a.pshd.server.poim.integration;uses:="javax.measure,javax.measure.uni
 t,org.core,org.utils.statuscodes,ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.domain.model,
 ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.integration,ru.focusmedia.pshd.server,ru.focus
 media.pshd.server.poim.db.entity",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.prot
 ocol;uses:="javax.measure,javax.measure.unit,org.core,org.utils.statu
 scodes,ru.focusmedia.jump,ru.focusmedia.jump.protocol,ru.focusmedia.o
 dp.pshd.domain.model,ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.ssd.domain,ru.focusmedia.
 pshd.server.poim,ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.integration,ru.focusm
 edia.pshd.server.poim.protocol.impl.commands,ru.focusmedia.pshd.serve
 r.poim.protocol.impl.commands.requests",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poi
 m.protocol.impl;uses:="ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.protocol.impl.s
 chemaslist",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.protocol.impl.commands;use
 s:="ru.focusmedia.jump,ru.focusmedia.jump.annotation",ru.focusmedia.p
 shd.server.poim.protocol.impl.commands.requests;uses:="ru.focusmedia.
 jump.annotation",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.protocol.impl.command
 s.responses;uses:="ru.focusmedia.jump.annotation,ru.focusmedia.pshd.s
 erver.poim.protocol.impl.commands",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.pro
 tocol.impl.schema;uses:="javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.bind.annotation",ru
 .focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.protocol.impl.schemaslist;uses:="javax.x
 ml.bind.annotation",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.protocol.tests;use
 s:="org.junit",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.schema_stubs;uses:="org
 .slf4j,ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.poim.bridge,ru.focusmedia.pshd.server,r
 u.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.db",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.sche
 ma_stubs.tests.manual;uses:="org.junit,ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.domain.
 model",ru.focusmedia.pshd.server.poim.tests.manual
Tool: Bundlor 1.1.0.BUILD-20101220120024
Import-Package: javax.measure,
 javax.measure.unit,
 javax.xml.bind,
 javax.xml.bind.annotation,
 javax.xml.namespace,
 javax.xml.parsers,
 javax.xml.xpath,
 org.core;version="[3.1.0,3.1.0]",
 org.slf4j,
 org.utils.statuscodes,
 org.w3c.dom,
 org.xml.sax,
 ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.domain.model,
 ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.entity,
 ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.integration,
 ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.integration.fb,
 ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.integration.roles,
 ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.integration.users,
 ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.repository.spi,
 ru.focusmedia.odp.pshd.ssd.domain
Import-Bundle: ru.focusmedia.jsr-275;version="[1.0.0,1.0.0]",
 org.apache.mina.core;version="[2.0.2,2.0.2]",
 ru.focusmedia.poim-protocol;version="[2.0.1,2.0.1]"
Bundle-SymbolicName: ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server
Bundle-Version: 3.2.0
Bundle-Name: ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server
Bundle-Vendor: focusmedia
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Library: org.springframework.spring;version="[3.0.0.RELEASE,3.0.5.RELEASE]"
```

I've also checked that the class file `work/org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer_2.1.1.RELEASE/staging/pshd.plan-3.2/bundle/pshd.plan-3.2-ru.focusmedia.poim-protocol/2.0.1/POIM_Protocol.jar/ru/focusmedia/odp/poim/protocol/AccessRights.class` is actually there after `ru.focusmedia.poim-protocol` is started.

Comment: Your second bundle, `ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.server` does NOT appear to import the package `ru.focusmedia.odp.poim.protocol`.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett: This version uses `Import-Bundle`. I've also tried replacing it with `Import-Package` (of all packages exported by `ru.focusmedia.poim-protocol`), this gives the same exception.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I didn't pay attention to that header because it is non-standard. Hmm my guess would be that the CNFE is not actually coming from your `poim.server` bundle but from some other bundle… for example perhaps the Spring JPA bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [Virgo FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Virgo/FAQ#How_can_I_diagnose_class_loading_problems.3F) for class loading diagnostic ideas.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the format of the first MANIFEST.MF file. Most OSGi implementations expect each line of a MANIFEST.MF file to be no more than 80 characters, and when an entry in the MANIFEST.MF file spans multiple lines, it expects the first character of each line in the entry after the first line to have a leading space. In the past, I've experienced only the first line of an improperly formatted entry in a MANIFEST.MF file to be read, which can cause all kinds of wonky behaviour.

In addition to that, you are using the "import bundle" directive to import a package. This should be in the IMPORT-PACKAGE section.

Comment: Could you clarify? I don't see any lines over 80 characters or continuations without leading spaces in first (or second) MANIFEST.MF :(